# How to block the sound of guest os in the host os?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vmware, vmware-player

I use VMWarePlayer to run windows 7 & 10 guest OS on windows 7 host os. I have a screen recording tool in my vm. I want that tool to capture video & also the sound coming from the VM. But, I don't want to hear this sound in while I am working on the host OS, with screen recording going on in the guest OS.

How do I block the sound of the guest os in the host os, without muting the speakers of the guest os ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Volume Mixer. This is a tool that lets you choose the relative volume of each application that can generate sound. Right-click on the speaker icon in your systray and choose mixer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Virtual Machine settings (Player > Manage > Virtual Machine Settings), select the virtual Sound Card device, and uncheck the Connected checkbox.